# $x(t),y(t)$- smooth curves who's normal vectors are collinear. If $y(t)=x(t)+\alpha(t)N_x(t)$ prove that $\alpha(t)$ is constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

$x(t),y(t)$- smooth curves who's normal vectors are ($N_x(t)$ and $N_y(t)$) collinear. If $y(t)=x(t)+\alpha(t)N_x(t)$ prove that $\alpha(t)$ is constant.

So I have that $x'(t)\neq 0, y'(t)\neq 0 $ and that $N_x(t)=cN_y(t).$

I do not know how to use these facts to put this together, or a direction as to how to go about solving this.
I use the following notations for the following concepts in class:

$T(t)$- tangent vector

$B(t)$ - binormal vector

$\tau(t)$ - torsion

$k(t)$ - curvature

Comment: Are your curves parametrized by arc length (i.e. canonically parametrized)?

Comment: It is not said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following steps:

1. Differentiate the relation $y(t) = x(t) + \alpha(t) N_x(t)$ with respect to time
2. Take the inner product on both sides with $N_x(t)$
3. Use the definition of normal and tangent vectors to see which terms are zero

This should give you the required result $\alpha'(t) = 0$.